# How to Pass selected items from a joined list to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm pulling data successfully and sending it to the ViewModel, but i can't seem to display the results in the view.

in my controller:

```
var verbiage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello World");

var productToDetail = _contentService
            .Products
            .Where(q => q.Id == 112)
            .Select(x => new { x.TypeId, x.Id, x.FullName, x.Length, x.Sku, x.Isbn, x.Price });

var model = new DetailPageViewModel
        {
            ProgramTables = GetUpComingCourses(),
            Verbiage = verbiage,
            CurrentProduct = productToDetail.ToList()
        };
return View(model);
```

in my viewmodel:

```
public string Verbiage { set; get; }
public IList CurrentProduct { get; set; }
```

in my view:

```
@Model.CurrentProduct.FullName;
```

The view sees that CurrentProduct is there, but gives me this error

'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no extension method 'FullName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for FullName, even though im clearly pullig it in the controller. I even quick viewed productToDetail and saw that the correct info was pulled.

I am at wits end! please help!

ok, so still i have NO IDEA why my data is not being pulled to the view....

**UPDATE**

in my controller:

```
    public static List GetCurrentApp(int item)
    {


        var productToDetail = _contentService
            .Products
            .Where(q => q.Id == item)
            .Select(x => new {x.TypeId, x.Id, x.FullName, x.Length, x.Sku, x.Isbn, x.Price});


        return productToDetail;
    }
```

*on return productToDetail; - Error: Cannot convert expression type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<{TypeId:int,Id:int, FullName:string,Lenth:string,Sku:string,Isbn:string, Price:string}>' to return type 'NHibernate.Mapping.List'*

```
 public ActionResult Details(int item)
    {

        var verbiage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello World");

        var model = new DetailPageViewModel()
        {
            Verbiage = verbiage,
            CurrentProduct = GetCurrentApp(item)
        };

        return View("../Shared/DetailView", model);
    }
```

In my Model:

```
public class DetailPageViewModel
{
    public string Verbiage { set; get; }
    public List CurrentProduct { get; set; }
}
```

In my View:

```
@model Project.Models.ViewModels.DetailPageViewModel
<h2>@Model.CurrentProduct.FullName</h2>
```

*Error on FullName*

:(

Comment: Are you trying to display a list of the `FullName` properties of each of the items in `CurrentProduct`? Or the name of just one of the items in `CurrentProduct`?

Comment: Just one. The selected items from the query.

Comment: If you want just one item from your query, you should use `First` or `Single` instead of `Where`

Comment: oh that was a typo. I but yeah from the code im just trying to pull one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the answer to this by ways of enumeration instead of single selected record. Simply send the data pulled to a seperated class within the model. Then Call the seperated class within the main ViewModel. The call an iteration in the view.

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string item)
    {

        var verbiage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello World");



        var productToDetail = _contentService
            .Products
            .Where(q => q.Id == item)
            .Select(x => new CurrentProduct
            {
                TypeId = x.TypeId,
                Id = x.Id,
                FullName = x.FullName,
                Length = x.Length,
                Sku = x.Sku,
                Isbn = x.Isbn,
                Price = x.Price
            });



        var model = new DetailPageViewModel()
        {
            Verbiage = verbiage,
            CurrentProducts = productToDetail
        };

        return View("../Shared/DetailView", model);
    }
```

in the viewmodel:

```
public class DetailPageViewModel
{
    public string Verbiage { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<CurrentProduct> CurrentProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentProduct
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@model Gcus.Com.Web.Models.ViewModels.DetailPageViewModel
<h2>@foreach (var item in Model.CurrentProducts)
                {
                    @item.FullName;
                }</h2>
```

easy. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the `CurrentProduct` in your model is a list of items. Judging by your query, it'll be a list of only one, but a list nonetheless.

A quick fix would be to put `@Model.CurrentProduct[0].FullName` in your view, but really you should adjust your query so that only a single object is returned. I'd do this:

```
var productToDetail = _contentService
        .Products
        .SingleOrDefault(q => q.Id == 112);

var model = new DetailPageViewModel
    {
        ProgramTables = GetUpComingCourses(),
        Verbiage = verbiage,
        CurrentProduct = productToDetail
    };
```

Be aware that `SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception if more than one result is returned with that Id, use `FirstOrDefault()` if you prefer it not to do that.

Comment: ok so im using:   var productToDetail = _contentService
                .Products
                .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == foundItemId)
                .Select(x => new { x.TypeId, x.Id, x.FullName, x.Length, x.Sku, x.Isbn, x.Price }); but it still gives me the same error on FullName

Comment: i have a feeling the problem is in my model but im not sure

Comment: The problem is you're doing the `Select` after the `FirstOrDefault`, which turns the result back into a list. Do you really need to do that `Select`? Otherwise, call `FirstOrDefault` again after the `Select`

Comment: yeah i have to use the select because im planning on joining more queries based on those selected items. But im at least trying to have those items placed in the view before adding to the query. But not sure why its not passing correctly.

Comment: i have this now. var productToDetail = _contentService
                .Products
                .Where(q => q.Id == foundItemId)
                .Select(x => new { x.TypeId, x.Id, x.FullName, x.Length, x.Sku, x.Isbn, x.Price })
                .FirstOrDefault(); But im getting the error: Cannot Convert source type {TypeId:ont, Id:int, FullName:strong, Length:string, Sku:string.Isbn:string, Price:string}' to target type NHibernate.Mapping.List'

Comment: You need to change the type of CurrentProduct in your view model to match the type of the object returned by your query.

Comment: yeah im not sure what that is, ive tried public IList CurrentProduct, public string CurrentProduct, List<CurrentProduct> CurrentProducts, etc. nothing  seems to work. But the data is there.

Comment: That's because your `Select` is returning an anonymous type. You'll need to make a new class with the same fields you are selecting, select into that and set the type of CurrentProduct to that.

Comment: Hm.. ok im not sure I'm understanding but i'll update the code with a class with the query...